# Como hago para que el progama me de el nombre del mayor y menor

Tags: c#, while

Hola hice  un programa básico donde me piden que introduzca varias edades y sacar la edad mayor, menor y el promedio, ahora me piden que ademas de esas acciones agregar los nombres y sacar el nombre del de mayor edad y el nombre del que tenga   menos edad. No tengo idea de como relacionarlo con el código si alguno me podría guiar seria de [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]gran ayuda

Comment: Muestra tu programa básico para asi poder guiarte.

Comment: Investiga sobre Clases, para crear objetos, es más fácil, lo otro es con matrices pero no te lo recomiendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrás que almacenar en alguna variable el nombre del mayor y nombre del menor.

```
string nombreMayor;
string nombreMenor;
```

Agrega en el while la solicitud de nombre antes de la edad:

```
Console.write("Nombre:");
string nombre = Console.ReadLine();
Console.write("Edad:");
...
```

Y finalmente guardarlo cada vez que encuentres uno mayor ( y de manera semejante para el menor)

```
if (edad > max) {
  max = edad;
  nombremayor = nombre;
}
```

Comment: Gracias fue de gran ayuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

no manejo C++ aún, pero buscando encontré lo siguiente (En Wikipedia), te va a ayudar:

> El ordenamiento por selección (Selection Sort en inglés) es un algoritmo de ordenamiento que requiere O{\displaystyle
> (n^{2})}{\displaystyle (n^{2})} operaciones para ordenar una lista de
> n elementos. Su funcionamiento es el siguiente:
>
> Buscar el mínimo elemento de la lista Intercambiarlo con el primero
> Buscar el siguiente mínimo en el resto de la lista Intercambiarlo con
> el segundo Y en general:
>
> Buscar el mínimo elemento entre una posición i y el final de la lista
> Intercambiar el mínimo con el elemento de la posición i De esta manera
> se puede escribir el siguiente pseudocódigo para ordenar una lista de
> n elementos indexados desde el 0:

```
para i=0 hasta n-1
    para j=i+1 hasta n
        si lista[j] < lista[i] entonces
            intercambiar(lista[i], lista[j])
        fin si
    fin para
fin para
```

> Ejemplo del algoritmo en C++:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
      for(int j = i + 1 ; j <= n ; j++){
            if(lista[i] > lista[j])
               intercambiar(lista , i , j);
         }
}
```

Seguir leyendo en: [link de Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_por_selecci%C3%B3n)

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberías preguntar si es la primera iteración del ciclo. Si es así,  en la primera vuelta asignas la edad a las dos variables y luego preguntas si la edad que viene por Consola es mayor a la edad mayor y si la edad que viene por consola es menor a la menor.

Te dejo un ejemplo. Creo que eso fue lo que preguntaste jajaja. Saludos.

```
    int edad_menor = 0, edad_mayor = 0, total_edades = 0;
    String nombre_edad_mayor = "", nombre_edad_menor = "";      
    Console.Write("Ingrese el número de datos (n): ");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        Console.Write("Edad: ");
        int edad = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());            
        Console.Write("Nombre: ");
        String nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                             
        if(i == 0){
            edad_menor = edad;
            edad_mayor = edad;
        }
        
        if(edad > edad_mayor){
            edad_mayor = edad;
            nombre_edad_mayor = nombre;
        }
        
        if(edad < edad_menor){
            edad_menor = edad;
            nombre_edad_menor = nombre;
        }
        
        total_edades = total_edades + edad;
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine("Nombre edad mayor = " + nombre_edad_mayor);
    Console.WriteLine("Edad mayor = " + edad_mayor);
    Console.WriteLine("Nombre edad menor = " + nombre_edad_menor);
    Console.WriteLine("Edad menor = " + edad_menor);
    Console.WriteLine("Promedio de edad = " + total_edades / n);
```